# OFX4J with American Express

Tags: java, financial, ofx, gnucash

So I'm trying to connect to American Express using OFX4J. I'm using the data provided in the OFX home page and I am getting a 503 error whenever I attempt to access the service. I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong.

I'm getting the Institution Data like so:

```
BaseFinancialInstitutionData amex = new BaseFinancialInstitutionData();
amex.setId( "424" );
amex.setFinancialInstitutionId( "3010" );
amex.setName( "American Express Card" );
amex.setBrokerId( null );
amex.setOrganization( "AMEX" );
amex.setOFXURL( new URL( "https://online.americanexpress.com/myca/ofxdl/desktop/desktopDownload.do?request_type=nl_ofxdownload" ) );
```

Then I'm opening the connection like they do in the example:

```
CreditCardAccountDetails ccDetails = new CreditCardAccountDetails();
ccDetails.setAccountNumber( "<my_card_number>" );
CreditCardAccount ccAccount = fi.loadCreditCardAccount( ccDetails, "<my_username>", "<my_password>" );

AccountStatement statement = ccAccount.readStatement( startDate, endDate );
TransactionList transactions = statement.getTransactionList();
List<Transaction> ledger = transactions.getTransactions();
```

But as soon as I attempt to access any data, I get the 503 error. Cursiously, Schwab works like a charm, so I'm assuming there is something wrong in the Institution Data?

Has anyone been able to get Amex going with OFX4J?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this institution data:

```
fid: 3101
org: AMEX
ofx: https://online.americanexpress.com/myca/ofxdl/desktop/desktopDownload.do?request_type=nl_ofxdownload
```

Comment: Works!! I had to set: 
OFXApplicationContextHolder.setCurrentContext( new DefaultApplicationContext( "QWIN", "1500" ) );

Answer (score 0):

["Some servers in this state may also simply refuse the socket connection..."](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html)

Many financial institutions do not differentiate between OFX (open) and QFX (proprietary).

If they are using Quicken licensed content, then they might not enable the service for non-Quicken applications (even if you can access the data files manually).  I attempted something similar with my bank and they let me connect, but started charging me a fee to recoup the licensing costs they had to pay to Intuit.

I would suggest talking to American Express' web support first, and if they indicate that the service is open and enabled (not a pay service, etc) then go back to troubleshooting your connection.

Comment: Hey Derek, they do support OFX as I can download it manually from the website. Have you had any luck with Amex before? Thanks!